Is action quantized to integer multiples of $h$ or $ħ$?
As I understand it, any observable/meaningful amount of Action (Energy * Time or Momentum * Distance) is always going to be an integer multiple of some value… $h$ or $ħ$, depending on the source.
I understand that when talking about the relationship of a photon’s frequency to its energy, one has the arbitrary choice to measure that photon by either its linear frequency $f$ or its angular frequency $ω$, and each one will give $h$ or $ħ$ as the proportionality factor.
Similarly, when calculating Angular Momentum, which has the same dimensions as Action, one also has the options of measuring the rotation by either $f$ or $ω$, giving $h$ and $ħ$ as the quanta of angular momentum respectively.
However, I don’t see this same or any equivalent choice appearing when considering the amount of action along a path, with it being energy * time or (linear) momentum * distance and therefore being possibly able to be thought about without any waves/photons and therefore that choice of how to measure, but instead with regular mass? Either way, that this amount must be an integer multiple of one of these two values, undoubtedly means some of the sources I’ve been reading from must’ve been wrong, they contradict each other:
Some explanations present $ħ$ as simply shorthand because of how often $h$ appears divided by  $2π$, and some even emphasized that the quantum of Action specifically remains the unreduced $h$ nonetheless, $ħ$ simply being something for convenience to hide $2π$ from a bunch of equations.
Other sources explain that $h$ has been completely phased out and replaced with $ħ$ even in the specific concept of the quantization of action, and that unreduced $h$ was either an earlier value that was refined later, or that the idea of unreduced $h$ being the quantum comes from the outdated old quantum theory Bohr-Sommerfeld model, and that newer more modern models work with action actually being quantized to integer multiples of $ħ$ instead.
Many of these sources also say that the quantization of action is experimentally observable, how then is it not agreed upon what this quantum is? Not that I can find anywhere saying there’s disagreement, but every other result in my search for my answer alternates between these two mutually exclusive answers.
So which is it, and why?

The action is most often used in the path integral formalism. But if you treat it as an operator, its spectrum may be discrete or continuous depending on the system.

"Is action quantized to integer multiples of h or ħ?" No. The action is not quantized to integer multiples of anything. The action is real valued.


Since the Boltzmann factor in the path integral is $$\exp\left(\frac{iS}{\hbar}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi iS}{h}\right),$$ then the difference of $\frac{S}{h}$ between two paths should be an integer to have constructive interference/superposition.
In other words, the on-shell action $\frac{S}{h}$ of a closed path should be an integer.

Semiclassically, the on-shell action $\frac{S}{h}$ jumps in multiples of $\frac{1}{4}$ because of the Maslov index/metaplectic correction/caustics.

The on-shell action $\frac{S(x_f,t_f;x_i,t_i)}{h}$ of an open path is not necessarily quantized.



They are not exclusive.  The expressions with $\hbar$ are usually multiplied by factors of $\pi$.  For instance, see these espressions for WKB bound states, which are of the form (some integer or half-integer)$\times \hbar 
\pi$.

Right, but that’s just equivalent to the ones saying it’s an integer multiple of h, which I’m saying is mutually exclusive with those that say it’s strictly an integer multiple of ħ by itself.  So you are implying here the answer is h but what would be the reason?

since $\hbar \times \pi=h/2$ you have some integer or half-integer multiple of $h/2$, i.e. not even an inter multiple of $h$.  Since you don’t quote your sources it is impossible to say more until you provide explicit details.

There is no inconsistency at all.
The old Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization of action says
$$\oint p_i\ dq_i=n_ih \tag{1}$$
where $(p_i,q_i)$ is any conjugate momentum/coordinate pair
and the integral is taken over one period of motion.
As an example apply (1) to the pair $L_z$ ($z$-component
of angular momentum) and $\phi$ (angle around the $z$-axis)
for a system with a Hamiltonian independent of $\phi$.
You get
$$\int_0^{2\pi}L_z\ d\phi=nh.$$
Since $L_z$ is conserved the integral is trivial to calculate and you get
$$2\pi L_z=nh$$
or
$$L_z=n\hbar$$
which is the well-known quantization of angular momentum.
